# MYSQL: distinct values in join - price is double counted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a report that joining 5 tables:

1 - Coupon Uses: `id - coupon_id - user_id - order_id`

2 - Coupon: `id - code - discount_type - discount_amount`

3 - Order: `id - user_id - orderread_ts - order_status`

4 - Payments: `id - user_id - order_id - sub - tax - discount - total - payment_collected`

5 - User: `id - email - fname - lname`

So I'm running a report that takes in several criteria: Promo name, user email, start date, end date.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    `Coupon`.`code` AS Promotion, 
    CONCAT('',o.`id`,'') AS Order_ID, 
    o.`orderread_ts` AS Order_Date, 
    u.`email` AS Customer_Email, 
    CONCAT(u.`fname`, " " ,u.`lname`) AS Name, 
    p.`subtotal` AS Subtotal, 
    p.`discount` AS Discount, 
    p.`total` AS Total 
FROM `Coupon` 
LEFT JOIN `Coupon_Uses` AS cu ON cu.`coupon_id` = `Coupon`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `Order` AS o ON o.`id` = cu.`order_id` 
LEFT JOIN `User` AS u ON u.`id` = o.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `Payments` AS p ON p.`id` = o.`id` 

WHERE `Coupon`.`code` = 'email10' 
AND o.`orderread_ts` > 0 
AND o.`order_status` = '' 
AND p.`discount` > 0 
AND p.`payment_collected` = '1'

GROUP BY o.`id`
```

I'm getting the correct results, however, if during checkout, the sale wasn't complete (bad payment, wrong cc entry, etc.) the table `Coupon Uses` will have two entries for the same `Order_id`.

Now, the order, when counted will be show incorrect information.

What I can't figure out is how to get distinct `order_id` from the `coupon_uses` table.

---

**UPDATED FINAL QUERY**

```
SELECT 
    c.`code` AS Promotion, 
    o.`id` AS Order_ID, 
    o.`orderread_ts` AS Order_Date, 
    u.`email` AS Customer_Email, 
    CONCAT(u.`fname`, " " ,u.`lname`) AS Name, 
    p.`subtotal` AS Subtotal, 
    p.`discount` AS Discount, 
    p.`total` AS Total 
FROM `Coupon` c 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT coupon_id, user_id, order_id
     FROM `Coupon_Uses`) AS cu ON cu.coupon_id = c.id
INNER JOIN `Order` AS o 
    ON o.`id` = cu.`order_id` 
INNER JOIN `User` AS u 
    ON u.`id` = cu.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN `Payments` AS p 
    ON p.`order_id` = cu.`order_id` 
WHERE c.`code` = 'email10' 
AND o.`orderread_ts` > 0 
AND o.`order_status` = '' 
AND p.`discount` > 0 
AND p.`payment_collected` = '1'
```

First change what the I used `SELECT DISTINCT` in the first join to make sure i'm getting only unique values. I joined each other table on the fields from `coupon_uses`, and I had an error in syntax on the last join, which is now fixed.

For performance: 683 rows affected, taking 30.1ms

Comment: Does such duplicate Coupon_Uses record not have a distinctive value somewhere, like a draft status? If so, you could add this to the join condition (`and cu.status <> 'Draft'). NB: those backticks are ugly. Take them out, they are only needed when you use reserved words, which you shouldn't.

Comment: @trincot - Sorry, I copy pasted from PHP and the freaking backticks are everywhere =\ I don't have time to refactor at this point in time as you can see, I have other issues. Thanks for Draft suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can have the situation where you have two records in the *Coupon_Uses* table which only differ in their *id* value. *coupon_id, user_id, order_id* could be the same...

If that is so, I would really suggest to look into that, as it doesn't seem right. Could you not write such a duplicate record in another table during the transaction, so you can ensure there are no such duplicates? Or could you not add a *status* column so the temporary record gets a *Draft* status, while all others are *Final*?

Anyway, if this is the situation, you can solve it as follows in the query:

Replace:

```
LEFT JOIN `Coupon_Uses` AS cu ON cu.`coupon_id` = `Coupon`.`id`
```

with:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT coupon_id, user_id, order_id
           FROM `Coupon_Uses`) AS cu ON cu.`coupon_id` = `Coupon`.`id`
```

But this could have a performance impact, as the join can probably not benefit from using an index.

Comment: So, you pointed me in the right direction and your suggestion worked. There are quite a few issues with this project and, unfortunately, the pile was handed to me. However, after implementing your solution, I also joined against the distinct select. Performance is currently at 40ms for 1MM records, so not bad. Thank You!